# COBOL: Printing A Line with a variable in it

Tags: variables, process, cobol, heading

Number of employees with up to 10,000 in sales: ZZ9

Number of employees from 10,001 to 20,000 in sales: ZZ9

Is what I'm trying to accomplish Where the ZZ9's are the variable. I'm not quite sure how to do this and I had my book stolen so was hoping for some help. In my WORKING-STORAGE SECTION I have

```
 01  HEADING-LINE-3.
            05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
            05                      PIC X(48) VALUE
                  "Number of employees with up to 10,000 in sales: "
 01  HEADING-LINE-4
            05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
            05                      PIC X(52) VALUE
                  "Number of employees from 10,001 to 20,000 in sales: "
```

And in my PROCEDURE DIVISION I have

```
 4000-PROCESS.
              WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM REPORT-BLANK-LINE.
              WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM COLUMN-HEADING-2.
              WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-3.
              WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-4.
```

but can't figure out how to add the variables in at the end of those statements. Any and all help is much appreciated. I started cobol like three days ago so if you could dumb everything as much as possible it'd be great!

Comment: ZZ9 is a PICTURE, which is an attribute of a variable, loosely speaking.  So you might code `05 HEADING-LINE-3-COUNT PIC ZZ9.`  And you can increment HEADING-LINE-3-COUNT, based on comparison logic, in your PROCEDURE DIVISION.  Short answer, because you're starting from square one: get another copy of your textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your numeric fields in at the end of the data declaration:

```
    01  HEADING-LINE-3.
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05                      PIC X(48) VALUE
              "Number of employees with up to 10,000 in sales: "
        05 Number-employee-to-10000  pic zzz,zz9
    01  HEADING-LINE-4
        05                      PIC X(03) VALUE SPACES.
        05                      PIC X(52) VALUE
              "Number of employees from 10,001 to 20,000 in sales: " 
        05 Number-employee-above-10000  pic zzz,zz9.
```

Do your record counts in 2 comp fields say

```
   01  ws-accumulators
       03 employee-accum-1      pic s9(9) comp. 
       03 employee-accum-2      pic s9(9) comp.
```

You should accumulate in these because Numeric-edited fields (pic zz9) are actually
text fields not numeric (and many compilers will not let you do it anyway). Comp fields
should be faster.

Then in the procedure division move the totals to the new fields above

```
   4000-PROCESS.
          Move  employee-accum-1        to Number-employee-to-10000 
          Move  employee-accum-2        to Number-employee-above-10000

          WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM REPORT-BLANK-LINE.
          WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM COLUMN-HEADING-2.
          WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-3.
          WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-4.
```

Comment: would you have to make number-employee-to-10000 and the other one? or could you simply put employee-accum-1 in its space in the heading lines

Comment: Depends on which version of Cobol you are using. Going back 10 years a Edited-Numeric (e.g. zzz9) was actually Character / String field and you would need the 2 variables. I think the latest standard allows for de-editing so some compiler will allow you to add 1 to a zz9 field. But to add 1 to the field, the computer needs to convert the field from the character representation to a binary integer, add 1 to it, then convert it back to a String.

Comment: @user38254 The PIC defines how a field is stored. Whenever that field is the *target* of a verb, any necessary conversion will take place. Putting a computational field of any type on a print line will not get you much in the way of visible results (occasionally you'll see something, but you won't know for sure what it means). Adding directly to a numeric-edited field would be very, very non-standard. Bruce has indicated the machinations that would be required, so hopefully once you know a bit more you'd never even consider it, even if you find a compiler which would allow it.